# preparing ZF2 query for a particular mysql query

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How can i prepare ZF2 query from the bellow mysql query

```
select (select category_name from categories where category_id = c.parent_id) as category_name
from 
ebook as e
join ebook_categories as ec ON ec.ebook_id = e.ebook_id
join categories as c ON c.category_id = ec.category_id
where
e.is_active = 1
group by category_name
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: iM really first to zf i have a small idea about normal select but dont know about sub queries

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using tablegateway in zf2. 
example:

```
public function fetchAllWithLikes( $user_id )
{
  $adapter   = $this->getAdapter();
  $resultset = $this->select( function( Select $select ) use ( $user_id, $adapter ) {

  $sub1   = new Select( 'likes' );
  $sub1->columns( array( 'total' => new Expression('COUNT(*)') ) )
      ->where( array( 'id' => new Expression( 'song_id' ) ) );

  $sub2   = new Select( 'likes' );
  $sub2->columns( array( 'total' => new Expression('COUNT(*)') ) )
      ->where( array( 'id' => new Expression( 'song_id' ) ) )
          ->where( array( 'user_id' => $user_id ) );

  $select->columns(
      array(
      'id',
      'title',
      'ytlink',
      'total_likes' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression( '?', array( $sub1 ) ),
      'your_likes' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression( '?', array( $sub2 ) ),
      )
  );

  var_dump( $select->getSqlString( $adapter->getPlatform() ) );

  });

  return $resultset->toArray();
```

}